Development of a GIS: Choice of database and considerations of scalability and Big Data
I am planning to develop a Geographic Information System (GIS) for the region where I live with the aim of optimising territorial management and promoting sustainable development. I have two main concerns: the choice of the database and the scalability to handle large volumes of data, known as Big Data.
Firstly, which database would be the most suitable for this project? I am debating between PostgreSQL with PostGIS and MongoDB, which database would be most efficient and easy to handle for storing and managing geospatial data in a GIS of this scale?
Also, I am concerned about scalability and the ability to handle large volumes of geospatial data in the future, especially with the prospect of Big Data. What are the recommended best practices and technologies to ensure scalability and efficient handling of Big Data in a GIS project of this scale?
I would appreciate any guidance or experience shared on these topics to ensure the success of the project and its ability to meet future demands for geospatial data in the region.
I'm trying to use Django with MongoDB, but I've encountered a lot of drawbacks, reading I've determined that maybe my best option is to use Django with PostGIS.

This question is likely to solicit highly opinionated answers.  I would suggest working out a skeleton design for your app, and then test.

@Joe These is our arquitecture initial:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AicjtULqD3XvDHOEeuL4tdFcvMQQJd5P/view?usp=sharing
But some suggestions within the development team thought it best to opt for this one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UICK1nvLfAQnjTIMk__mnDFkWXZ3LhGU/view?usp=sharing
